# How does the AudioInputStream.read(byte[] b) function work?

Tags: java, arrays, byte, javax.sound.sampled, audioinputstream

I have a problem with [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioInputStream.html#read(byte[])) method.
In the following i have written a test code that reads an audio stream into a byte array (and does a convertion [i have mp3plugin.jar as external jar, if you should wonder why this works] and some other stuff, but i have only let that in to make the code executable).
**The problem is that the method seams not allways to do the same thing. Sometimes the AudioInputStream is getting smaller and sometimes it is not. My question is why?**

```
package doej.test;

import java.io.File;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;

public class Test2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        int totalFramesRead = 0;
        File fileIn = new File("D:/User/Music/eclipseTestfiles/test.mp3");
        try {
            AudioInputStream mp3Stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(fileIn);
            AudioFormat sourceFormat = mp3Stream.getFormat();
            AudioFormat convertFormat = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, sourceFormat.getSampleRate(), 16, sourceFormat.getChannels(), sourceFormat.getChannels() * 2, sourceFormat.getSampleRate(), false);
            AudioInputStream converted = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(convertFormat, mp3Stream);
            int bytesPerFrame = converted.getFormat().getFrameSize();
            int numBytes = 1024 * bytesPerFrame;
            byte[] audioBytes = new byte[numBytes];
            try {
                int numBytesRead = 0;

                //My simplified Test part
                System.out.println(converted.available());
```

Ok, so this is the original size of the audio stream. (Until here everything is fine)

```
                System.out.println("read " + converted.read(audioBytes));
                System.out.println(converted.available());
```

Why **is** my Stream getting smaller? (in the documentation they say it is reading into the array so i kinda understand that part)

```
                System.out.println("read " + converted.read(audioBytes));
                System.out.println(converted.available());
```

Why **is** my Stream **not** getting smaller, as it did the first time? (for this is the part i have no clue)

```
                while ((numBytesRead = converted.read(audioBytes)) != -1) {
                    System.out.println(converted.available());
```

Why **is** the Stream now getting smaller **every eleven times**? (here I don't understand the world anymore)

```
                }
                //End of my test part

            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
            System.out.println("finished");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Finally this is the output i get:

```
6043688
read 4096
6035592
read 4096
6035592
6035592
6035592
6035592
6035592
6035592
6035592
6035592
6035592
6035592
6029324
6029324
6029324
[...]
4444
4444
4444
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
finished
```

Thanks for your help.

John

Comment: what is it that you want to do? read the available() method - and just go ahead and do it

Comment: Actually I want to write a program  that cuts the dynamic range of songs. the read()-method did what I wanted, because when I looped through "audioBytes" I got the binary output of a frame that i expected.

Comment: After that I couldn't really export the AudioInputStream because it had only 44KB instead of 42,3MB when I export it before using the read()-method. I realized that the method rips the frames out of the AudioInputStream while reading. That is the point I started to experiment to see what behavior the read()-method has. The code above is the result of those experiments. Furthermore, I realized that this method rips the frames out only sometimes. That is so irrational that I posted it over here.